# How to add additional child node inside a unique key in firebase realtime android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, insert

I want to include surname inside that unique key together with full name and student id. I am quite stuck and this is probably my last resort. I don't know what to do in the coding. Your answer will definitely a big help. Thank you so much!

```
 {

  "Students" : {

    "-Ma9R58DvoFMkLqukMmk" : {
      "fullname" : "Juan Capistrano Dela Cruz",
      "studId" : "18-ln-0001"
    },
    "-Ma9TttvUqShhYjD-q_5" : {
      "fullname" : "Maria Acosta Gomez",
      "studId" : "18-ln-0002"
    },
    "-Ma9Ub__33IsWEFDbitu" : {
      "fullname" : "David Orosco Villar",
      "studId" : "18-ln-0003"
    },
    "-Ma9ZI_FvEgutnSvsSrU" : {
      "fullname" : "Ara Quizon Diaz",
      "studId" : "18-ln-0006"
    },
    "-MaBPU-fsEInFUGWft_n" : {
      "surName" : "Diaz"
    }
  }
}
```

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

String userId = databaseReference.child("Students").push().getKey();

String surname = snameInput.getText().toString();

HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put("surName", surname);


databaseReference.child("Students").child(userId).setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(PersonalData.this, "Surname updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show: 1) the data structure in your database (as JSON text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) the code of what you already tried, or of the context of where you are trying to add this property.

Comment: I hope that you can help me Sir, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the student ID of the node you want to update, then you can take a two-step process:

1. Use a query to find the nodes with that student ID.
2. [Update that node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write)/those nodes.

In code that'd be:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("Students").orderByChild("studId").equalTo("18-ln-0002");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot resultSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot studentSnapshot: resultSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            studentSnapshot.getRef().child("surname").setValue("Cortez");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

---

In general though, if your student IDs are already unique, then it makes more sense to use *those* as the keys for the nodes under `Students`. So in that case you'd add a student with:

```
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put("fullname", "Maria Acosta Gomez");

databaseReference.child("Students").child("18-ln-0002").setValue(hashMap);
```

And updating them would then be as simple as:

```
databaseReference.child("Students").child("18-ln-0002").child("surname").setValue("Cortez");
```

Or if you want to use the hashmap:

```
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put("surName", snameInput.getText().toString());

databaseReference.child("Students").child("18-ln-0002").updateChildren(hashMap);
```

Comment: I tried your solution yet it didn't solve my problem. The flow of my code is that you can add a new student's number and full name. And the list of new students will show. After that, if you click one list, the next window would add the user's other information. That's why I need to add the surname but it cannot go to the same unique key.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you did with the code I shared. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to make it most likely we can help.

Comment: Hey @LeonicaCortez. Any further updates here?